# Python running code prevents me from typing in the console

Tags: python, while-loop

```
import getpass
import sys
import msvcrt

passwor = ''

while True:
  x = msvcrt.getch()

  if x == '\r':
    break

  sys.stdout.write('*')
  passwor += str(x)
    
print('\n' + passwor)
```

I can not type in the console after I try to run the code. Thinking it is due to the while loop, but I have no clue on how to break it correctly.

If you guys have any thoughts on what I can do to fix the code so it can accept the enter key and stop the while loop, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you try checking what the value of `x` ends up being, when you press enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return is in bytes. Your condition should check `b'\r'` to break. Also, you have to `flush` `stdout` to print the asterisk.

```
import sys, msvcrt

def getPassword():
    sys.stdout.write('Password: ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
    pw = b''                  #init password as bytes

    while True:
        char = msvcrt.getch() #get typed character - returns as bytes
        if char == b'\r':     #if character is return, break
            break
        pw += char            #else concat password with character
        sys.stdout.write('*') #write asterisk 
        sys.stdout.flush()    #flush buffer to print asterisk
        
    return pw.decode()        #return password as string

pw = getPassword()
print(f'\n{pw}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should temporarily put something like:

```
print(x)
```

immediately after the `getch` call, it may be that you're getting something *different* to `'\r'` (like `b'\r'` for example, which is what I see when I do that). Hence *that* is what you should be comparing against:

```
if x == b'\r':
```

Perhaps the *best* way to check this is simply to fire up Python and see what it does for specific keys. The following transcripts shows wat happened when I pressed the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```
C:\Pax> python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import msvcrt
>>> print(msvcrt.getch())
b'\r'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import getpass
import sys
import msvcrt    
passwor = ''
while True:
    x = msvcrt.getch()
    if x == '\r':
        break
    sys.stdout.write('*')
    passwor +=str(x)
    
    print('\n'+passwor)
```

You have had an indentation error. I think it may help you. If not, please pardon me because I am a beginner in this field

Comment: Show us the full error traceback! Meanwhile you can also check if you have mixed spaces ans tabs for indentation.

Answer (score -1):

use break and remove indentation before while.

```py
import getpass
import sys
import msvcrt    
passwor = ''
while True:
        x = msvcrt.getch()
        if x == '\r':
            break
        sys.stdout.write('*')
        passwor +=str(x)
        print('\n'+passwor)
        break
```

hope it would be helpful :)